# I need to show the captured picture in grid layout dynamically in the same activity where my camera screen is there in android

Tags: android, camera

I have created a custom camera application and i am saving the captured images in the gallery but i want to capture the image and should save it in the same screen below to the camera layout (layout where i have the next arrow in the screenshot) dynamically.I don't want save the captured in my local device it should only be stored in the grid layout. I have searched and worked but it didn't work. Thanks in advance.Please help me to figure out this.

I have searched in these links:

http://blog.andolasoft.com/2013/06/how-to-show-captured-images-dynamically-in-gridview-layout.html

https://developer.android.com/training/camera/photobasics.html

Here is my code:

Camera_Activity.java

```
 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.cameraactivity);
    ButterKnife.inject(this);
    surfaceHolder = surfaceView.getHolder();
    surfaceHolder.addCallback(this);
    surfaceHolder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);
    btn_take_photo.setOnClickListener(new ImageButton.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            cameraImage();
        }
    });
    jpegCallback = new Camera.PictureCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
            FileOutputStream outputStream = null;
            File file_image = getDirc();
            if (!file_image.exists() && !file_image.mkdirs()) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "cant create directory to save image", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return;
            }
            SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyymmddhhmmss");
            String date = simpleDateFormat.format(new Date());
            String photofile = "Cam_Demo" + date + ".jpg";
            String file_name = file_image.getAbsolutePath() + "/" + photofile;
            File picfile = new File(file_name);
            try {
                outputStream = new FileOutputStream(picfile);
                outputStream.write(data);
                outputStream.close();
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            } catch (IOException ex) {
            } finally {

            }
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Picture saved", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            refreshCamera();
            refreshGallery(picfile);
        }
    };
}

private void refreshGallery(File file)
{
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE);
    intent.setData(Uri.fromFile(file));
    sendBroadcast(intent);
}

private void refreshCamera() {
    if (surfaceHolder.getSurface() == null)
    {
        return;
    }
    try {
        camera.stopPreview();
    }   catch (Exception e) {}
    try {
        camera.setPreviewDisplay(surfaceHolder);
        camera.startPreview();
    }catch (Exception e){}
}

private File getDirc()
{
    File dics= Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM);
    return new File(dics,"CameraDemo");
}

public void cameraImage() {
    camera.takePicture(null, null, jpegCallback);
}

public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder) {
    try {
        camera = Camera.open();

    } catch (RuntimeException ex) {
    }
    Camera.Parameters parameters;
    parameters = camera.getParameters();
    parameters.setPreviewFrameRate(20);
    parameters.setPreviewSize(352, 288);
    camera.setParameters(parameters);
    camera.setDisplayOrientation(90);
    try {
        camera.setPreviewDisplay(surfaceHolder);
        camera.startPreview();
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }
}

@Override
public void surfaceChanged (SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder,int i, int i1, int i2){
    refreshCamera();
}

@Override
public void surfaceDestroyed (SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder){
    camera.stopPreview();
    camera.release();
    camera=null;
}
```

}

Camera_Acitivity.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/btn_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/layout_area"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:background="#000"
    android:layout_height="50dp">
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/btn_flash"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:src="@mipmap/flash"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp" />
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/btn_switch"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:src="@mipmap/flash"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp" />
</RelativeLayout>


    <SurfaceView
        android:id="@+id/surfaceview"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_above="@+id/layout_area1"/>

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/btn_take_photo"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"

        android:cacheColorHint="@android:color/transparent"
        android:backgroundTint="#00000000"
        android:layout_above="@+id/layout_area1"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:onClick="onClick" />




    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/layout_area1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:background="#000"
        android:layout_height="100dp">
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/btn_exit"
            android:src="@mipmap/next"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:nestedScrollingEnabled="false"
            android:onClick="onClick" />



    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can cache it in memory using Bitmap object instead of storing it in file.

```
public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera){
    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data, 0, data.length);    
}
```

Now the question arise that how you can Broadcast the Bitmap. Well for that you have to encode the Bitmap into Base64 String & decode it.

There is one more option currently I've in my mind is Observer Pattern. You can define an Observer class globally and and define modules & Interface having Bitmap as an arguments inside it. Once image captured notify to the Observer class method which in turn notify all the observing classes registered to this Observer class through interface.

**Note: The above mentioned method will takes up a lot of memory depending upon the size and count of images. So just to keep the memory overhead as less as possible. You can compress the original Bitmap which will reduce it's size and quality.**

```
public Bitmap getCompressedBitmap(Bitmap original, Bitmap.CompressFormat format, int quality){
        ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        original.compress(format, quality, out);
        return BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(out.toByteArray()));
}
```